# wc in background does not return

Tags: bash, shell, background, wc

**In what scenario will a `wc -l` in `bg` not return?**

**And the case below in particular**

I have a snippet similar to the one below in a shell script,

```
file_name=my_file_name.xyz
```

In one loop,

`wc -l ${file_name}` & bg_pid=$!

In another loop,

```
wait ${bg_pid}
```

I actually have an array of file_names and I put the `wc -l` for each in the background and [`wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/wait.html) on their `pid`s in another loop.

`wc -l` on these files when done in the foreground gets completed. However, `wc -l` does not return when put in `bg`

---

Actually I want to do

```
count[i]=`wc -l ${file_name[i]}` & bg_pid=$!
```

This wouldn't work either cause bg process can't return a value that way (and I don't want to write to a file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question at the top of your post, "wc -l" in background will not return when the input stream to wc doesn't provide end of file, so if you do this, for example:

```
cat - | wc -l
```

and then don't type anything.

Comment: That was very helpful. The filename being passed was blank.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you are wondering why *in your code* `wc -l` might not return, right? Consider this command:

```
wc -l ${file_name}
```

If `${file_name}` evaluates to the empty string, then you are running:

```
wc -l
```

which reads on `stdin` until `stdin` ends. If nothing is closing `wc`'s `stdin` then `wc` will wait, and wait.... and wait.....

Comment: Exactly. I restructured the code moving the initialisation out of scope